# I need to call Activity from Fragment in android

Tags: android

Here, my application have fragment like this

```
public class FreeTicketFragment extends Fragment
```

My application have activity like this

```
public class ticket2 extends FragmentActivity
```

I want to call ticket2 class from FreeTicketFragment. How to call this activity???
Please help..

Comment: call 'getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),ticket2.class));'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ticket2.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
    Intent  intent   =   new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ticket2.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I don't think so. I myself use this when I want to call an Activity from a Fragment and it works just fine

Answer (score -1):

Call `getActivity()` after `onAttach(Activity activity)` is run.